# c++11 share_ptr as value a map key

Tags: pointers, c++11, share

**I just insert  pValue to map next i get it from map ,and its value should be 20 ,but not, why?**

```
typedef  shared_ptr<BaseObject> PtrValue;
class CodeExecuteContext{
     public:
     map<string,PtrValue> varIdentPool;
};  



class BaseInteger :public BaseObject{
    public:
        int value;
        BaseInteger(int val):value(val){
            enumObjType = INT;
        };
};

...

PtrValue pValue = rightNode->executeCode(context);
context.varIdentPool.insert(make_pair(leftNode.idName,pValue));

BaseInteger * baseInteger = (BaseInteger *) pValue.get();
cout << "==AssignmentASTFork==  insert [ " << leftNode.idName << " , " << baseInteger->value << " ]" <<endl;

map<string,PtrValue>::iterator it;
for (it = context.varIdentPool.begin() ; it!=context.varIdentPool.end();it++) {
    BaseInteger * baseInteger = (BaseInteger *) it->second.get();
    cout << "[key : " << it->first << ", value : " << baseInteger->value << endl;
}
```

result:
==AssignmentASTFork==  insert [ arg , 20 ]
[key : arg, value : 32742]

Comment: My guess would be, the map already contains this key. `map::insert` is a no-op in this case - it doesn't replace the existing value with new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map::insert function returns "pair", where the boolean from the pair indicates whether the element has been inserted or not. If the boolean is true, it has been inserted. If the key already existed, the boolean will be false and the key-value pair has not been inserted.

Try "auto insertResult = context.varIdentPool.insert(make_pair(leftNode.idName,pValue));"
If insertResult.second == false, the key already existed.

The iterator (insertResult.first) will always point to the item from the map.

With that iterator you can alter the value from the map by "insertResult.first->second = newValue"

Comment: it works ! I insert the same key into map , somewhere . so if exist the same key , it will fail not replace the old value when insert

Comment: If you want insert-or-update semantics, use `map[key] = val` instead of `insert`.